# Saving canvas data to server and retrieve only a piece?

Tags: php, mysql, html5-canvas

I'm working on an art piece and I have been searching and combing through the internet for help, and there really is a lot, but I really don't understand it.

About a month ago I dove into html and CSS and have been forced to learn bits and pieces of Javascript in about 2 weeks for this piece... I now know that I need PHP and this is where I have the most problem. Here are the problems.

I have a html5 canvas where a user can doodle. What I would love is that he/her be able to press a button and his/her image be sent to a server (I assume using PHP) and that the image be kept until another person opens the doodle webpage. I would like it to be a collective art piece: someone draws something, submits it, someone else goes into the page and a PIECE of another person's "art" is already there to be built up. Ideally this would be random but for the moment I would just be happy for the image to be sent to the server and a piece put back on the page the next time it is opened.

I know I have to use a form with a hidden field? This is what I have found out, but honestly I don't know what that means and how to do it. I found this code:

```
<form action="Drawing.html" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="formImageFileName" name="imageFileName">
<input type="hidden" id="sketch" name="imageData" value="" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveImageButton" value="Save Image..." />
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('my_hidden').value = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
document.forms["form1"].submit();
</script>
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
$upload_dir = somehow_get_upload_dir();
$img = $_POST['my_hidden'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir."image_name.png";
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
header('Location: '.$_POST['return_url']);
?>
```

and when the button is clicked, the image disappears. I don't know if it's going anywhere or if it's just been wiped away? 
I tried to do it alone but I have decided I need help. I am a big newbie with PHP, like seriously the biggest newbie. I have no idea what any of that does and I would really appreciate it if someone were to explain it to me in simple terms and how to proceed. I did some reading and I know why there are $ and what the POST is and I read up on mysql, but I don't know how to access a server or retrieve data or anything.

Please, I am at the end of my rope. Thank you in advance to anyone feeling generous.

PS: Please no sarcastic comments, if I left anything out please let me know. I already feel bad for having no idea how to do this, and would prefer not to feel worse because I forgot to include something. And please no comments on how there are many places to find what I am looking for, if I have come here, it's because I need serious help and those places aren't cutting it with my time constraints.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When you press submit, your client (browser) uploads the image to the server, **but** now expecting a page to load now. You have to re-send the page with the canvas and its content from the server.

Comment: Sorry but answering that... means writing an application for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a *huge* quantity of knowledge that not only includes coding but also includes configuring your PHP server and your MySQL server. That much info is probably too much to answer here.

This is a *very summarized* list of what you have to achieve:

- Configure your PHP server’s php.ini to allow uploads.
- Configure MySQL and PHP to work together.
- Create a MySQL database and table(s) to store your images.
- Create the .php file to allow users to upload files or use XMLHttpRequest() to do uploads for them.
- Add the script that takes POST or FILE submitted and puts the image into your database.
- Create the .php file to allow users to “check-out” a file from the database.
- Add the script that selects the proper image from the database and downloads it to the user.
- Handle concurrency issues on MySQL if multiple users are allowed to check out the same file    simultaneously.

I read that you are new to html, webservers & databases so I expect this list to be challenging for you at the moment.  So here is my suggestion:  Sign up for a Lynda.com free trial membership.  They have very good web seminars dealing with web topics.  I’m not affiliated with Lynda.com (no sales pitch here!), but I do find their seminars a good learning tool.

In particular, watch these chapters in the tutorial called “PHP with MySQL Beyond the Basics”:

- Photo Gallery Project Setup
- Uploading Files
- The Photograph Class

Good luck and keep coding…with persistence and some studying, your pieces will fit together!